# How to modify sentence parsing rules in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

While parsing list of strings the current rules allow comma to be at the end of the sentence and not allow comma to be between words, which is obviously not correct. How to modify current rules?

```
complexsentence --> [] ; simplesentence, complexsentence;
                   simplesentence, delimiter, complexsentence.
simplesentence --> noun, verb.
delimiter --> [,].
noun --> [sun].
verb --> [shines].
% TEST: phrase(complexsentence, [sun,shines]). %must be TRUE
% TEST: phrase(complexsentence, [sun,',',shines]). %must be TRUE
% TEST: phrase(complexsentence, [sun,shines,',']). %must be FALSE
```

---

Update:
Tried to solve it like this. It works

```
complexsentence --> [] ; simplesentence,complexsentence.
simplesentence -->  noun,verb;
            noun,verb,delimiter,noun;
            noun,verb,delimiter,noun,verb.
delimiter -->[,].
noun-->[sun].
verb-->[shines].
% TEST: phrase(complexsentence, [sun,shines]). % TRUE
% TEST: phrase(complexsentence, [sun,',',shines]). % FALSE
% TEST: phrase(complexsentence, [sun,shines,',']). %FALSE
```

Comment: Why is the second case "must be TRUE"? And why is `[]` a valid `complexsentence`?

Comment: He needs that to get solutions, but it would be more intuitive (I think) to say `simplesentence` instead of `[]`.

Comment: @DanielLyons yes, that's what I was thinking `complexsentence --> simplesentence.` would make more sense than `complexsentence --> [].`

Comment: @mbratch That solves the problem, by the way. You should submit that as an answer.

Comment: Of course, the second test cannot be true unless `simplesentence//0` becomes `simplesentence --> noun ; verb ; noun, verb.`, because as written, a sentence must have a noun and a verb, and that isn't the case in the second test.

Comment: @DanielLyons yes, that was my first question. :)

Comment: @mbratch It would be rad if I could read. :)

Comment: I need `[]` to be able to end recursive calls, because `complexsentence` is defined by itself. Why I have to give up `[]`?

Comment: @RCola you have to give up `[]` because that is what gives rise to the erroneous `[sun,shines,',']` result. What has literally been parsed there is a `simplesentence` of `sun, shines` and then a complex sentence of `[]`, separated by `','`. Changing it to `simplesentence` ensures that you have a noun and a verb on both sides of a delimiter, always, or no delimiter at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggested change to DCG:

```
complexsentence --> simplesentence.  %was []
complexsentence --> simplesentence, complexsentence.
complexsentence --> simplesentence, delimiter, complexsentence.
simplesentence --> noun, verb.
delimiter --> [,].
noun --> [sun].
verb --> [shines].
```

Then:

```
% TEST: phrase(complexsentence, [sun,shines]). %will be TRUE
% TEST: phrase(complexsentence, [sun,',',shines]). %will be FALSE (as it should)
% TEST: phrase(complexsentence, [sun,shines,sun,shines]). %will be TRUE
% TEST: phrase(complexsentence, [sun,shines,',',sun,shines]). %will be TRUE
% TEST: phrase(complexsentence, [sun,shines,',']). %will be FALSE
```

I'm suggesting the second test should be FALSE since the problem description indicates, *...and not allow comma to be between words*.

Although the original clause (`complexsentence --> [].`) provided a termination case for the recursive definition of `complexsentence`, it had two issues: (1) it defined the empty sentence as the simplest complex sentence, and (2) it allowed a trailing delimiter on a valid complex sentence (via the 3rd clause, since you could get `simplesentence, delimiter, []`. Using `complexsentence --> simplesentence.` as the base case makes more logical sense and fixes the second issue as a bonus, since your other cases are logical in that context.

Comment: @RCola I attempted to provide some explanation in my edited answer, which I hope is helpful.